# Efficient way to search a string with no Delimiter in SQL

Tags: sql, substring

I have a column that is `VARCHAR(MAX)` where I need the information immediately following a unique identifier.

The unique identifier is 3 characters ('a3c') and the information I need is either a 1 digit or 2 digit number.

The column is in multiple databases that I am searching. Most of the databases have around 100,000 rows, but one database I need to research has over a million lines.

Currently I am using `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` to find what I need:

```
SUBSTRING([col], CHARINDEX('a3c', [col]) + 3, 2)
```

This is extremely inefficient when looking at the database that has over a million line.  I am also looking to add a `CASE` statement (the digits after the identifier are a reference number) and I know that is going to slow the whole query even more.

Some more information about the column:

- The data in the rows varies from 45 to 500 characters.
- Not every row contains contains the unique identifier.

Adding `[col] LIKE '%a3c%'` to the `WHERE` clause does not speed up the query very much.

Is there a more efficient way to search a 500 character `VARCHAR(MAX)` row?

Comment: How often does this query need to be executed? And does the data it returns need to be current up to the minute?

Comment: The most efficient way is to not store your data like that.

Comment: If your data in the column is not a single discreet value you are violating the basic first-normal principle, which is always going to cost you, as this demonstrates. Maybe an indexed computed column would be the way to go.

Comment: What @stu said. I was thinking more along the lines of a new clustered column store table and a sproc that runs periodically to aggregate the results from the various databases into it, so that querying is nearly instantaneous, but that depends entirely on how current the data has to be.

Comment: @MikeHofer, this would be a daily query for the most part. The store table might be something I can schedule overnight.

Comment: @Stu I looks like an index wouldn't work because the column is a `varchar(max)`.

Comment: @JohnHowieson *The data in the rows varies from 45 to 500 characters*.... so what's wrong with `varchar(500)`? Using `(max)` carries additional overhead if your data is *not* potentially more than 8k